# Many-to-many relationship between tables - how to model in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm just wondering what the best implementation for a simple example like this is.

If I have 2 tables below and a unit has multiple upgrades which are variable amounts I was thinking of holding a list of IDs of upgrades in an CSV format then I'd load the unit and extract the ids from the list of upgrade IDs.

I just feel like there might be a better way to implement this because It's been quite a while since I've worked in SQL and I'm not sure if this is best practice or any issue that I might not foresee.

Tables

Unit
{
ID,Name,Upgrades
}

Upgrade
{
ID,name,description
}

Comment: This is called normalization. First approach (comma separated values) violates 1 Normal Form (only atomic data in column)

Comment: Is the relationshsip one-to-many or many-to-many?  Basically can one Upgrade be associated with multiple Units?  For one-to-many you'd want a foreign key in the Upgrade table.  For many-to-many you'd want a separate table that maps unit and upgrades to each other.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a many-to-many relationship : a unit can have many upgrades and an upgrade can be set on many units.

You may create a middle table like UnitUpgrade :

```
Unit     UnitUpgrade     
Id   --- UnitId          Upgrade
Name     UpgradeId   --- Id
                         Name
                         Description
```

Comment: Yea multiple units could also have the same upgrades. I didn't think of a middle table that makes a lot of sense I haven't used SQL in quite a while so wasn't sure of the best approach thanks.