# Resolving table(mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql

I got 3 table, called class , student and class_student(resolving table) . This is due to many to many relationship between class and student. A student can have many class and a class can have many student. The fields inside class is(class_id, class_start_time and class_end_time) , student(student_id, student_name, student_age) , class_student(student_id , class_id). My question would be : Inside a class, it includes student , how do I add student into the class table ? Or should I make use of the resolving table? My understanding of resolving table is weak and I'm not sure what's the purpose of it.

Thank you all for your answer !

What about when I add a new record to class student table , do I add a new record to class table as well?

Comment: It is totally normal to use that kind of table, `class_student` in your example. when you need many-to-many relationships. You can proceed with it.

Comment: `"how do I add student into the class table"` - Um, you don't.  You connect the records using the table between them, exactly as you've described.  What's the problem?

Comment: I think a more common term is _relation table_.

Comment: When you create a student you add a row to the student table. When you add a student to a class you add a new row to the class_student table (class_id and student_id). That way you can list all students connected to that class

Comment: When I add a student to class , a new row will be added for class_student table. Does it means that a new row will be added for class as well?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [Many-to-many relationship between tables - how to model in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088333/many-to-many-relationship-between-tables-how-to-model-in-sql) and many others.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to resolve a many to many relationship is via a seperate `relation table` (as Barmar noted).

In your case that table could have these fields:

```
table class_students
--------------------
id      // an unique id of that relationship; 
        // could be ommitted, could be an autoincrement, 
        // could also be a "handcrafted" id like classid_userid -> 21_13 (I need this kind of id's for an ember-api. 
        // All depending on your needs
class   // the id of the related class
student   // the id of the related student
// maybe add additional fields:
type     // to describe that relationship
sort
```

You then would get all the students of a specific class like so:

```
$class_id = 1;
$sql = "Select * from students, class_students where students.id=class_students.student AND class_student.class=".$class_id;
// note, that you should do that via prepared statements, 
// this is only for simplicity to show how to proceed.
```

Comment: What about an insert statement ? Do I insert student into class_student table only ? How about class table?

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to add students in the class table. If you do so, there is no point separating class from student in the first( you have prevented redundancy of data ). I believe the table structure is good enough to achieve your objectives. The secondary keys (student_id , class_id) which are primary key in the student and the class tables respectively does the job.

class table

```
id|  title  | start | end
1   Biology    8am    10am
2   English    10am   12pm
```

student table

```
id | name |
1    John
2    Doe
```

student_class table

```
student_id  | class_id
1               1
1               2
2               1
```

from the table, i could

1. Get all courses John( user.id: 1 ) registered for

   ```
   SELECT FROM student_class WHERE student.student_id  = '1'
   ```
2. All the students that registered for Biology (class.id: 1)

   ```
   SELECT FROM student_class WHERE student.class_id  = '1'
   ```

   **Note** I know you will need the name of the student here in the result.
   Very simply , just 'LEFT JOIN' class table with student_class table on student_class.class_id = student.id

Then for each record you get from student_class table, the 'name' (or other columns you choose to include in the result set) will be added from the class table.

**Note** the way you just joined the `class` table, you can do the same for `student` table. for example, You want the student to print their time table for classed they registered for, you will still select from `student_class` table and get the `start` and the `end` time using `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: What about an insert statement ? When I add a new record to class_student table , I will need to add a new record for class as well. How do I do that?